# Debugging python memory leaks

Tags: python, debug, empathy, memory

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in [telepathy-butterfly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telepathy-butterfly/+bug/591119). I tried to use valgrind, but Empathy does not connect to MSN when telepathy-butterfly is run this way.
So, I figured out the only option left is to debug the memory leak by printing object sizes from within the code.

I was able to get all objects (using the `gc` module) and print their sizes and types. The leak seems to come from a dictionary (or dictionaries), which have no `__name__` property, so I can't tell where their coming from.
I tried to check all objects in `globals()`, but it looks like they are not related to the dictionaries that leak.

Since this is my first time hunting memory leaks in unfamiliar python code, I thought it is best to ask for advice. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: While your question is on topic here since you're trying to debug a program in Ubuntu, I think you'll get a better response on the sibling site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which is for programming questions.

Comment: This question would probably get more good quality answers on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler/110826

They suggest [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) amongst others.